# Passing argument from incompatible pointer type warning

Tags: c, pointers

I've been trying to figure out pointers in C most of today, even asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159498/need-some-help-understanding-pointers-and-memory-in-c) earlier, but now I'm stuck on something else. I've got the following code:

```
typedef struct listnode *Node;
typedef struct listnode {
    void *data;
    Node next;
    Node previous;
} Listnode;

typedef struct listhead *LIST;
typedef struct listhead {
    int size; 
    Node first;
    Node last; 
    Node current; 
} Listhead;

#define MAXLISTS 50

static Listhead headpool[MAXLISTS];
static Listhead *headpoolp = headpool;

#define MAXNODES 1000 

static Listnode nodepool[MAXNODES];
static Listnode *nodepoolp = nodepool;

LIST *ListCreate()
{
    if(headpool + MAXLISTS - headpoolp >= 1)
    {
        headpoolp->size = 0;
        headpoolp->first = NULL;
        headpoolp->last = NULL;
        headpoolp->current = NULL;
        headpoolp++;
        return &headpoolp-1; /* reference to old pointer */

    }else
        return NULL;
}

int ListCount(LIST list)
{
    return list->size;

}
```

Now in a new file I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "the above file"

main()
{
    /* Make a new LIST */
    LIST *newlist; 
    newlist = ListCreate();
    int i = ListCount(newlist);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

When I compile, I get the following warning (the `printf` statement prints what it should):

```
file.c:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ListCount’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Should I be worried about this warning? The code seems to do what I want it to, but I'm obviously very confused about pointers in C. After browsing questions on this site, I found that if I make the argument to ListCount `(void *) newlist`, I don't get the warning, and I don't understand why, nor what `(void *)` really does...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ListCount accepts LIST? what is LIST? where is it defined? you pass it LIST*

Comment: The code would be much more easier to read/debug for you if you didn't `typedef` a pointer type.

Comment: From my limited understanding, LIST is a pointer to a struct, called Listhead. Am I right?

Comment: @Alok: it could still work of the name was `ListPtr` instead of `LIST`

Comment: @Alok Is there another way to `typedef`? Or is it generally not necessary? I don't want to have to use `struct list` wherever I want to use a list...

Comment: @hora: `LIST` is synonym for a type that is a pointer to `struct listhead`.  In other words, you can replace `struct listhead *` for `LIST`, `struct listhead **` for `LIST *`, etc.

Comment: @hora: there is a difference between `typedef struct listhead LIST` and `typedef struct listhead *LIST`.  In the first case, `LIST` is a synonym for `struct listhead`, in the second case, it is a synonym for `struct listhead *`.

Comment: @hora: Is this your code, or an example that you found to help understand pointers?

Comment: @Alok: When should I be using each method? (`typedef struct listhead LIST` vs `typedef struct listhead *LIST`)

@e.James: It's my code mixed with some example code from `The C Programming Language` book by Kernighan and Ritchie.

Comment: @hora: Many people (me included) consider it a good idea to *never* typedef away the pointer, just typedef the struct. Hiding the asterisk is a bad idea since it generally crops up when you use the type anyway, and it's just confusing.

Comment: @hora: see my answer, but you probably don't want *any* typedefs if you're just learning things.  Once you get comfortable with types, then you can have typedefs if you would like.  As unwind said, many people don't ever typedef pointers (except function pointers of course!)

Comment: @Alok: I wish I could, this is for an assignment and we have to do it this way. Not really the easiest thing to jump into without any C experience.. Talk about a crash course.

Comment: @hora, good luck.  The real fun will begin when you have to remove lists and keep track of which index has valid list and which doesn't! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting confused because of multiple typedefs.  `LIST` is a type representing a pointer to `struct listhead`.  So, you want your `ListCreate` function to return a `LIST`, not a `LIST *`:

```
LIST ListCreate(void)
```

The above says: `ListCreate()` function will return a pointer to a new list's head if it can.

Then you need to change the `return` statement in the function definition from `return &headpoolp-1;` to `return headpoolp-1;`.  This is because you want to return the last available head pointer, and you have just incremented `headpoolp`.  So now you want to subtract 1 from it and return that.

Finally, your `main()` needs to be update to reflect the above changes:

```
int main(void)
{
    /* Make a new LIST */
    LIST newlist;  /* a pointer */
    newlist = ListCreate();
    int i = ListCount(newlist);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh wow OK I see what was going on. @unwind's comment above helped me understand what I was doing with the typedef. So I think I made LIST a pointer to the struct in the typedef, and then when I tried to create a pointer things weren't happy. I changed the way that works so now I'm pretty sure I ended up with the equivalent to your suggestion, just written in a less confusing manner. Thanks!

Comment: Can this warning be forced to report as error instead?