# c string basics, why unassigned?

Tags: c, string, char, declaration, variable-assignment

I am trying to learn the basics, I would think that declaring a char[] and assigning a string to it would work.
thanks

```
int size = 100;
char str[size];

str = "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd";
```

gives error "incompatible types in assignment". what's wrong?
thanks

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124935/c-strings-confusion/2125429#2125429

Comment: Arrays are not pointers ... and pointers are not arrays ... read this: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Answer (score 7):

You can use a string literal to *initialize* an array of char, but you can't *assign* an array of char (any more than you can assign any other array). OTOH, you *can* assign a pointer, so the following would be allowed:

```
char *str;

str = "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd";
```

Comment: hm.thanks for help. this is weird to me, that i can declare str[size], then use something like fgets(3) to write to that memory, or strcpy(str2, str) to write to it, but can't set str = "string here";  why is that?

Comment: I'd use a `const char*` when dealing with string literals.

Comment: @alfo: It's simply that C doesn't allow you to modify an array by assigning the contents of another array to it using `=`.  There's not really a deep reason *why* - it's just that the language requires you to use another mechanism (`memcpy()` in general) to do that.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually one of the most difficult parts of learning a programming language.... str is an array, that is, a part of memory (size times a char, so size chars) that has been reserved and labeled as str. str[0] is the first character, str[1] the second... str[size-1] is the last one. str itself, without specifiying any character, is a pointer to the memory zone that was created when you did

```
char str[size]
```

As Jerry so clearly said, in C you can not initialize arrays that way. You need to copy from one array to other, so you can do something like this

```
strncpy(str, "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd", size); /* Copy up to size characters */
str[size-1]='\0'; /* Make sure that the string is null terminated for small values of size */
```

Summarizing: It's very important to make a difference between pointers, memory areas and array.

Good luck - I am pretty sure that in less time than you imagine you will be mastering these concepts :)

Comment: no `str` isn't a pointer. Do a `sizeof str` to see the difference. The easiest way to see it that `str` is 'silently' converted into a pointer on the 'right hand side' of expressions, but not on the left of the assignment statement.

Comment: Yes, Jens, you are right- I stand corrected. Thanks a lot for pointing it out :)

Comment: Also you're misusing the word *initialize* in the paragraph beginning "As Jerry so clearly said".

Comment: My apologies, English is not my primary language.

Answer (score 2):

A char-array can be implicitely cast to a char* when used as Rvalue, but not when used as Lvalue - that's why the assignment won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign array *contents* using the `=`operator.  That's just a fact of the C language design.  You can *initialize* an array in the declaration, such as

```
char str[size] = "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd";
```

but that's a different operation from an assignment.  <strike>And note that in this case, and extra '\0' will be added to the end of the string.</strike>

The "incompatible types" warning comes from how array expressions are treated by the language. First of all, string literals are stored as arrays of `char` with static extent (meaning they exist over the lifetime of the program).  So the type of the string literal "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd" is "<strike>4</strike> 5-element array of `char`".  However, in most circumstances, an expression of array type will implicitly be converted ("decay") from type "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.  So, when you wrote the statement

```
str = "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd";
```

the type of the literal was implicitly converted from "<strike>4</strike> 5-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", but the target of the assignment is type "100-element array of `char`", and the types are not compatible (above and beyond the fact that an array expression cannot be the target of the `=` operator).

To copy the contents of one array to another you would have to use a library function like `memcpy`, `memmove`, `strcpy`, etc.  Also, for `strcpy` to function properly, the source string must be 0-terminated.

**Edit** per R's comment below, I've struck out the more dumbass sections of my answer.

Comment: The string literal `"\x80\xbb\x00\xcd"` already contains a terminating 0, so it's misleading to talk about the final 0 being "added" when using it as an initializer. Further, a partially-initialized object in C always has the remainder of the object zero-filled. This is not specific to strings.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a String Literal to the `str` Array you can use a the String copy function `strcpy`.

Comment: To be more precise: you copy characters (the string 'content') rather than "assigning" a value.

Comment: Yes, assign is not correct. I wanted to point out the possibility how to set the str Array.

Answer (score 0):

`char a[100] = "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd";` OR `char a[] = "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd";`

Answer (score 0):

str is the name of an array. The name of an array is the address of the 0th element. Therefore, str is a pointer constant. You cannot change the value of a pointer constant, just like you cannot change a constant (you can't do 6 = 5, for example).

Comment: Yes, str is an array of characters. But the name str itself, when used in that context, is a pointer constant. Maybe the terminology I used is different, but what else would you call str when used in that context, str = "\x80\xbb\x00\xcd";

Comment: "The name of an array is the address of the 0th element. Therefore, str is a pointer constant." You appear to have issue with this statement, so I will clarify. I refer to the address of as a pointer constant. For example, suppose you have int x; int *y ; y = &x ;  Here, &x is [what my colleagues and I call] a pointer constant--it is a value which is an address of some other place in memory, and it cannot be changed. It is not a pointer. Aside from that, what issues are there with my post?

Comment: The problem is that the expression `str` isn't always treated as a pointer. Here's the relevant paragraph (section 6.3.2.1, para 3) " **Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array** , an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined."  Emphasis mine.

Comment: Also, what you call pointer constants are more commonly known as rvalues (i.e. the value of an expression).