# Segmentation fault when returning a struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to do a pretty simple thing - it is reading a file and then turning it into a char** splitting it into lines. However when I return a struct containing the char** and size i get Segmentation fault. I read here: [C segmentation fault before/during return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047163/c-segmentation-fault-before-during-return-statement) that it's probably "mangled stack". I still however don't know what I did to mangle it. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "comp_words.h"
#define BLOCK 4096

struct sized_str {
    char* str;
    long size;
};

struct sized_arr {
    char** content;
    int size;
};

struct sized_str readfile(char* name) {
    FILE *f;
    long filesize;
    char *buf;
    struct sized_str res;
    int r, p = 0;

    f = fopen(name, "r");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    buf = calloc(filesize + 1, sizeof(char));
    while ((r = fread(buf + p, sizeof(char), BLOCK, f))) {
        p += r;
    }
    res.str = buf;
    res.size = filesize + 1;

    return res;
}

struct sized_arr read_dict() {
    struct sized_str file_content;
    struct sized_arr result;
    char *buf, *buf_cpy, *buf_cpy_point, *line, **res;
    int i = 0, j, line_count = 0;

    file_content = readfile("/var/tmp/twl06.txt");
    buf = file_content.str;
    buf_cpy = (char*)malloc(file_content.size * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buf_cpy, buf);
    buf_cpy_point = buf_cpy;

    while (strtok(buf_cpy_point, "\n\r")) {
        line_count++;
        buf_cpy_point = NULL;
    }

    res = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * line_count);

    while ((line = strtok(buf, "\n\r"))) {
        res[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(line));

        j = 0;
        while ((res[i][j] = tolower(line[j]))) {
            j++;
        }
        buf = NULL;
    }
    free(buf_cpy);
    result.size = line_count;
    result.content = res;

    return result;
}

// ...

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sized_str input;
    struct sized_arr dict;

    dict = read_dict();

    // ...
    return 0;
```

The code segfaults while returning from read_dict function.

Comment: what are contents of that file? i can't reproduce

Comment: @Andrey: The code above probably isn't the whole thing. It's quite likely that the segfault occurs *after* the call to `read_dict`, when `dict` is actually accessed.

Comment: @casablanca probably, but i want to reproduce it as it is

Comment: although @casablanca is probably right (+1 for that) there are some memory issues here: the `strcpy` should really be a `mempcy` of `strncpy` instead, although the `calloc` saves the day. The `read()` should read `filesize` max instead of reading until reading 0; a growing file will corrupt memory when read in like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to increment `i` after storing each line into the result array, so you end up storing all lines into `res[0]`. But you still set `result.size = line_count` at the end, so all array elements beyond the first are undefined. An `i++` at the end of this loop: `while ((line = strtok(buf, "\n\r")))` should fix it.

Comment: +1, nice catch. @zefciu - we call this being 'snow blind', or staring at the same thing for so long that you really don't see anything at all anymore.

Answer (score 3):

At least at first glance, this seems to have a couple of problems. First:

```
while ((line = strtok(buf, "\n\r"))) {
```

To use `strtok` you normally pass the buffer on the *first* all, then make subsequent calls passing "NULL" for the first parameter until `strtok` returns a NULL (indicating that it's reached the end of the buffer). [Edit: upon further examination, it's apparent this isn't really a bug -- as pointed out by @Casablanca, he sets `buf` to NULL in the loop so the second and subsequent iterations actually *do* pass NULL for the first parameter -- so the current code is a bit hard to understand and (at least arguably) somewhat fragile, but not actually wrong.]

Second, when you allocate your space, it looks like you're not allocating space for the terminating NUL:

```
res[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(line));
```

At least at first glance, it looks like this should be:

```
res[i] = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
```

[As an aside, `sizeof(char)==1` and casting the return from `malloc` can mask the bug of failing to `#include <stdlib.h>` to get a proper prototype in scope.]

Some of your other code isn't exactly wrong, but strikes me as less readable than ideal. For example:

```
j = 0;
while ((res[i][j] = tolower(line[j]))) {
    j++;
}
```

This appears to be a rather obfuscated way of writing:

```
for (j=0; line[j] != '\0'; j++)
    res[i][j] = tolower((unsigned char)line[j]);
```

Also note that when you call `tolower`, you generally need/want to cast the parameter to `unsigned char` (passing a negative value gives undefined behavior, and quite a few characters with accents, umlauts, etc., will normally show up as negative in the typical case that `char` is signed).

You also seem to have a memory leak -- `read_dict` calls `readfile`, which allocates a buffer (with `calloc` -- why not `malloc`?) and returns a pointer to that memory in a structure. `read_dict` receives the structure, but unless I've missed something, the struct goes out of scope without your ever freeing the memory it pointed to.

Rather than try to find and fix the problem you've seen, my immediate reaction would be to start over. It seems to me that you've made the problem considerably more complex than it really is. If I were doing it, I'd probably start with a function to allocate space and  read a line into the space, something on this order:

```
// Warning: Untested code.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readline(FILE *file) { 
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t current_size = 1;
    char *temp;
    const int block_size = 256;

    do { 
        if (NULL == (temp = realloc(buffer, current_size+block_size)))
            break;
        buffer = temp;
        buffer[current_size-1] = '\0';
        if (fgets(buffer+current_size-1, block_size, file)==NULL) 
            return strlen(buffer) > 0 ? buffer : NULL;      
        current_size += block_size-1;
    } while (strchr(buffer, '\n') == NULL);

    strtok(buffer, "\n");
    if (NULL != (temp = realloc(buffer, strlen(buffer)+1)))
        buffer =temp;
    return buffer;
}
```

Once that's working, reading all the lines in the file and converting them to upper-case comes out something like:

```
// Warning: more untested code.
while (res[i] = readline(file)) {
    size_t j;
    for (j=0; res[i][j]; j++)
        res[i][j] = toupper((unsigned char)res[i][j]);
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: +1 for catching the misuse of `strtok`, which is the bug lurking in the corner and waiting to bite after the OP fixes the low hanging fruit.

Comment: It really isn't a bug. The OP sets `buf` to `NULL` inside the loop, so all iterations starting with the second will pass `NULL` to `strtok`, which is correct.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I am quite new to low-level programming so your patience in showing me my mistakes is deeply appreciated.

Also thanks for the alternative for my usage of strtok.