# What is the difference between these two sorting functions using "ptr[i]" and "*(ptr+i)"?

Tags: c

```
void sort(int *ptr, int n) {
    int i,j,tmp;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=i;j<n;j++)
                if (ptr[i] > ptr[j])
                {
                    tmp=ptr[i];
                    ptr[i]=ptr[j];
                    ptr[j]=tmp;
                }
}
```

AND

```
void sort(int *ptr, int n) {
    int i,j,tmp;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=i;j<n;j++)
                if (*(ptr+i) > *(ptr+j))
                {
                    tmp=*(ptr+i);
                    *(ptr + i) = *(ptr + j);
                    *(ptr + j)=tmp;
                }
}
```

It has the same output. Both works. I've seen people using both, although obviously the first one seems more natural and intuitive than the second. Is there any problems whatsoever in using the first one over the second? Also, what are the main differences between them, if any?

Comment: It's just a matter of style. Functionally it's exactly the same. I would assert that most people would say the first one is much more readable.

Comment: Maybe this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/233148/1741542

Comment: Main difference is the 2nd takes up more text.

Comment: Why are you using bubblesort?

Comment: BTW, they both could start the nested loop from `j = i + 1`.

Comment: @Bob__, in that case, you must also fix the outer loop.

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, good point ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two pieces of code are semantically equivalent.

Section 6.5.2.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the array subscript operator `[]` states:

> A  postfix  expression  followed  by  an  expression  in  square 
>   brackets `[]` is  a  subscripted designation of an element of an array
>   object.  The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that
>   `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion
>   rules that apply  to  the  binary `+`operator,  if `E` 1is  an  array
>   object  (equivalently,  a  pointer  to  the initial  element  of  an 
>   array  object)  and `E2` is  an  integer, `E1[E2]` designates  the
>   `E2`-th element of `E1` (counting from zero).

So for example `ptr[i]` is exactly the same as `*(ptr+i)`, as well as other similar instances.

The first version of the code using array subscripting is generally preferred because it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. It's merely a matter of style.